# Php update performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance

a script of mine produces all the required details of a product page for an eshop.

I use one query at the top to SELECT product details, another one to select the category name (via foreign key category_id) and another one to fetch the manufacturer's brand name.... pretty simple...

everything works fine...

I have recently altered my code to include an UPDATE query so as to create statistics for the products by updating a single field on a single product...

products table currently uses 1500 rows...

i tried updating the product by these two ways:

**classic method:**

```
$new_times_viewed = $row_product['times_viewed'] + 1;
UPDATE products SET times_viewed = 300 WHERE product_id = 125 LIMIT 1;
```

**mysql method:**

```
UPDATE products SET times_viewed = times_viewed + 1 WHERE product_id = 125 LIMIT 1;
```

both ways make this pirticular page load a lot more slowly... the admin of the server informed me that i create a huge load on the server in terms of CPU. I have tried loading the script on another production server an works fine and fast as hell... both servers work via MyISAM engine...

it is definately this update that causes the problem since excluding it solves the performance issue.

is there somthing wrong with my logic or is it a server config problem? 
it is driving me mad...

thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume you're looping through products to update them?

Comment: no, its just a product page no loops... one record update

Comment: if it works elsewhere fine then it is a server configuration issue.

Comment: as long as i know both servers work with nginx, however, on the server where the problem is encountered PHP is used via php-fpm and not as a module... if this hepls...

Comment: Is that only query which is taking significant time, or all query running slow?

Comment: only this update query... if i exclude this query everything is very fast.. no cpu load at all... Its mindblowing... one single update in a single row, on a single column causes all this load... HOW?

Comment: there should be essentially no difference between doing the addition in mysql v.s. doing the addition in php. the real load will be from the 'where' clause, especially if it's a big table.

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to update a row dynamically that doesn’t exist yet?

Comment: @MarcB the WHERE here is limited to 1 row via LIMIT 1 and via product_id...on a 1500 row table this shouldnt be a matter...

Comment: @Phillip no this is not hapenning

Comment: Why the 'limit 1'? I would expect product_id to be a unique key hence only one row updated, and if not which occurrence of that key would you like to update? Are both times_viewed and product_id numeric type fields?

Comment: @Kickstart LIMIT 1 is not needed, you are right, it has been added for testing purposes when the problem was found... both fields are numeric, however, product_id is also unique (primary key) and autoincrement...

Comment: That it works fine on another server suggests it isn't this (quite simple) query that is the problem. Possibly a table locking issue?

Comment: The problem has been solved by changing the db engine from MyISAM to InnoDB via phpMyAdmin. Its working fine without unwanted loading peeks..